# Исключить из выборки все записи левой таблицы по условию в правой

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, postgresql, sqlite

Вопрос по классическому сыкулю.
Имеются две таблицы, связанные по ключу. Ключ левой - уникален. Ключ в правой – нет. Т.е. отношение один ко многим. Естественно что JOIN таких таблиц даст результирующую таблицу, в которой записи левой таблицы будут повторены столько раз, сколько им соответствуют записи в правой. Если мы зададим условие отбора записей правой таблицы, то можем исключить некоторые записи, не удовлетворяющие заданному условию.  Вопрос следующий: как исключить из объединения ВСЕ записи левой таблицы, если наше условие будет удовлетворено хотя бы для одной. Пример:

```
CREATE TABLE left(id INT, name VARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO left(id,name) VALUES('1', 'first'),('2', 'second'),('3', 'third');

CREATE TABLE right(id INT, condition BOOLEAN);
INSERT INTO right(id,condition) VALUES(1, 0),(1, 1),(2, 0),(2, 0),(3, 1),(3, 1);
```

Пробуем так:

```
SELECT l.id,l.name,r.condition FROM left l JOIN right r ON l.id = r.id WHERE r.condition = 1
```

И получаем вывод:

```
id  name    condition
1   first   1
3   third   1
3   third   1
```

Задача исключить из результата id==1 name==first потому что в правой таблице для этой записи есть хотя бы одна с condition == 0

Comment: Оставьте одну DBMS, удалите лишние теги.

Answer (score 1):

Классические варианты:

```sql
SELECT t1.*
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.f1 = t2.f2 AND t2.f3=@value
WHERE t2.f2 IS NULL
```

```sql
SELECT *
FROM t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                   FROM t2
                   WHERE t1.f1 = t2.f2
                      AND t2.f3=@value )
```

Варианты с NOT IN тоже имеют право на существование - но они, как правило, медленнее.

---

Конкретно для таблиц и данных из вопроса для SQLite 3.8 (для других указанных СУБД даст ошибку синтаксиса):

```sql
SELECT l.id,l.name,r.condition 
FROM left l
JOIN right r ON l.id = r.id 
WHERE r.condition = 1
  AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                  FROM right rr
                  WHERE l.id=rr.id
                    AND rr.condition=0)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, ближе к тексту примера. Если Вы внимательно его смотрели, то кроме реляции 1-ко-многим по ключу (у Вас t1.f1 = t2.f2) есть еще некоторое условие по полю, ключевым не являющимся (r.condition = 1)

Comment: @An0ther0ne Дополнительные условия по правой таблице при левом связывании - добавляются в ON clause. Уж такие-то простые вещи можно было добавить и самостоятельно... ок, код исправлен.

Comment: Насколько я понял, на стаковерфлов нет простых или сложных вещей. Есть вещи работающие и нет. К тому же я не вижу в чем проблема повторить мой пример и дать ответ в терминах вопроса. Разве что Вы хотите создать дополнительные проблемы всем остальным, заставляя производить подстановки. Вобщем по первой части Ваш пример не работает как того требовалось. Я произвел точную подстаноку и получил SELECT left.* FROM left LEFT JOIN right ON left.id = right.id AND right.condition = 1 WHERE right.id IS NULL
что вернуло мне id=2 а не id=3, как то требовалось по условию.

Comment: А работает следующий пример: SELECT left.* FROM left LEFT JOIN right ON left.id = right.id AND right.condition != 1 WHERE right.id IS NULL
Т.е. разница кардинальная и принципиальная: с точностью до наоборот. Вторую часть сейчас проверю.

Comment: Со вторым примером точно такая же история.
Рабочий пример: SELECT * FROM left WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM right WHERE left.id = right.id AND right.condition != 1)

Comment: @An0ther0ne Если надо ИСКЛЮЧИТЬ - то оператор используется НЕ РАВНО. *Есть вещи работающие и нет.* Вам дан ШАБЛОН. Не зря написано - "Классические варианты". Который Вы дальше строите как нужно. А совсем готовые ответы с гарантией бывают только на фрилансе.

Comment: И здесь встречаются, поверьте.Ваш покорный слуга к примеру всегда выкладывает проверенные и рабочие варианты. К тому же я не прошу чегото сверхъестественного, а всего лишь решить тестовый пример, который я набросал за 2 минуты времени. Вы тестовые задачи как решаете? Просите препода дописать за вас код и подогнать результат с ответом?

Comment: @An0ther0ne В нынешнем виде вопрос В ПРИНЦИПЕ не допускает готового ответа. Ибо: 1) 4 разных сервера БД - перебор; 2) не указана версия СУБД - у каждой из них свои заморочки. Вот, к примеру (добавлено в ответ), запрос - устроит?

Comment: @An0ther0ne *Вы тестовые задачи как решаете?* Если для решения тестовой задачи мне пришлось обратиться за консультацией, то первое, что я делаю - это разбираю, что и почему мне подсказали, как это работает, и как это применить для решения моей задачи. И не постесняюсь переспросить то, что не пойму. И уж точно не бросаюсь обвинять консультанта в том, что он мне дал не готовый ответ, а подход к решению.

Comment: Эту тестовую задачу я уже решил самостоятельно спустя примерно полчаса после постановки. Посмотрите там выше мой ответ. Но ведь нет предела совершенства. Поэтому и хотелось посмотреть на более элегантные решения если они существуют. Ваше дополнение хоть и выдает две записи для id=3, но по условию засчитывается. Благодарю за ответ (сразу бы так). Ничего личного.

Comment: @An0ther0ne *Ваше дополнение хоть и выдает две записи для id=3* не понял... а сколько нужно? я ориентируюсь только на то, что есть в вопросе... а он намекает на необходимость получения отдельных записей, даже если они полные дубликаты. Если дубликаты необходимо "схлопнуть" - решение будет совсем иным.

Comment: Поэтому и засчитывается. Я убрал минус и плюсонул Ваш ответ, если Вы не заметили.

Answer (score 0):

Вобщем я пока придумал такой способ. Может у кого будут идеи получше, пишите.

```
SELECT * FROM left WHERE left.id NOT IN (SELECT l.id FROM left l JOIN right r ON l.id = r.id WHERE r.condition != 1)
```

Или полный вариант:

```
SELECT * FROM left ll JOIN right rr ON ll.id=rr.id AND ll.id NOT IN (SELECT l.id FROM left l JOIN right r ON l.id = r.id WHERE r.condition != 1) GROUP BY ll.id
```